# Eager loading problem

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I've a problem with this linq to nhibernate query

```
var listeShopping = (from cart in session.Query<Cart>()
    .Fetch(cart => cart.ItemShopping)
    .ThenFetch(item => item.Manufacturer)
    select cart.ItemShopping).ToList<ItemShopping>();
```

When I launch it I've a strange error :

```
Query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was
not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,
fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=_1,role=,tableName= (...)
```

I need the eager loading, how can I avoid that error ? If it can help, I'll mention that I use the cart table only like a inner join table. I just need to know the ItemShopping in the Cart.

Regards

**Edit**

I modified the code to make it readable in english. I corrected the error.

**Edit 2**

I found that method, it seems to work ... Can someone check it if I didn't make an error ?

```
        var list = (from item in session.Query<ItemShopping>()
                   .Fetch(item => item.Manufacturer)
                   from cart in item.Cart
                   select item).ToList<ItemShopping>();
```

Comment: where is the `pan` in the `select` defined ?

Comment: You are quering Cart's, selecting something from pan and trying to cast it to list of ItemShopping... Some details needed :)

Comment: I modified the code ... sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to handle this scenario with Linq. But it is with HQL:

```
var listeShopping = session.CreateQuery(@"
    select item
    from Cart cart
    join cart.ItemShopping item
    join fetch item.Manufacturer
    ")
    .List<ItemShopping>();
```

Side note: eager fetching the Manufacturer this way is not necessarily the best performing approach. Consider using `batch-size` in the Manufacturer class instead.

Comment: Why should I use Batch-size instead of eager loading ? What are the pro and the cons ? I simplified by request, I have 10 Fetch and I don't have enough volume to have some production performance test.

Comment: @PhilippeSohm: 10 fetch? you should be using batch-size *and* caching, not fetch. Using batch size allows for small, efficient queries per entity type, while using multiple fetch statements creates huge joins that are much more costly.

Comment: Is caching efficient for a web application ? If I have a query like var items = (from item in session (...) select item) and then a foreach (var item in items) var data = item.Manufacturer.Name. Is batch-size efficient ?

Comment: @PhilippeSohm: yes. Considering your Manufacturers don't change every day, you're looking at huge query savings.